# VueJS method is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, asynchronous, graphql

In my vue project, i want to fetch something from graphql and store it to a variable.
function is async and the value of rawID must be awaited for. Since this could obviously also result in undefined, the "generateID" complains that it is undefined. Im a TS native dev and in TS i would just tye this as something OR undefined but in js that doesnt work.

```
async click() {
            const rawID = await generateID()
            const ID = rawID.data.theDataINeed
            console.log(rawID, ID)
        },

        generateID() {
            const CREATE_ID = gql`
                mutation {
                    theDataINeed
                }
            `
            return this.$axios.post('theGraphQLEndPoint', {
                query: print(CREATE_ID),
            })
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with since you're probably using Options API and have `generateID` defined in `methods`

```js
await this.generateID()
```